# Share Model between Xamarin.Forms Shared Project and Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

I am a newbie to Xamarin.Forms and building an app using Xamarin.Forms Shared Project Template. The app connects with a Web API written in ASP.NET. The Web API `POST()` takes a model as a parameter to save into database.

What are the best practices to share the model between both of them to avoid rewriting the model in the mobile app?

Comment: In which project does your models currently reside? If they need to be accessible by both your ´Xamarin.Forms` and `ASP.NET` project, and your `Xamarin.Forms` project refers to your `ASP.NET` project, then I would suggest simply placing the models in your `ASP.NET` project.

Comment: Are you using an EDMX in your ASP project?

Comment: Yes, I am using EDMX in ASP project. My ASP.Net project is not referred in Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: You can't. If you want to use the transferred data as objects, you have to write a model in Xamarin.Forms and deserialize it. You can only simplify the model by passing the necessary data that you need in your client.

Comment: @Elvis, this means I will need to write the model in my Forms project as well?

Comment: @Nitesh, Yes, you will need to write the model in your Forms project.

Comment: Thanks @ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: If we are rewriting the models in both ASP.Net & Xamarin.Forms project, how do we handle the foreign key objects. For ex - API.Models.Task model has a reference to API.Models.User object. How do we handle this in App.Models.Task class? It is throwing 400 bad request

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same with my existing project. I created a separate project, we will call it the Framework project, just for models being shared between other projects. The problems I ran into were around dealing with platform specific properties, SQLite annotations (with XF models), Entity Framework annotations (with Web API project), and Entity Framework being ridiculous when it comes to base classes.

I had to get rid of my EDMX and go down to only POCO models in my separate Framework project.

Both projects had different annotations that needed to be on certain properties, I did install Newtonsoft.Json into the Framework project since both Web API and XF projects used the `JsonIgnoreAttribute`:

- For the ASP Web API project, I was using EF which did some weird stuff when trying to create tables from models that derived from the Framework models in the separate project. So I was able to recreate attributes that were needed such as `DisplayFormatAttribute` and `DisplayNameAttribute` in the Framework project. (let me know if you have problems making them, I do not think I would have been able to recreate more than a few very basic ones, fyi). In order for those custom attributes to be used, you must derive from `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` and set your new derived class in the **Global.asax** file on `ModelMetadataProviders.Current`.
- The XF project had SQLite annotation that I did not want to install into Framework project so I derived from each Framework model that needed to be overriden and overrode the properties to add the annotations within the XF project.

Currently there is a [bug](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/549) in sqlite-net-pcl (version 1.3.3) that prevents annotations from working with overriden properties. Fallback to 1.3.2 until it is fixed.

Framework Model Example:

```
public class ExpenseModel {
    [DisplayName("Something Other Than Id")] //XF just ignores this, EF uses it
    public virtual int Id {
        get; set;
    }

    [DisplayName("Expenses")]
    public virtual List<Expense> Expenses {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

XF Derived Model Example:

```
public class ExpenseModelDto : ExpenseModel {

    #region Properties

    /* 
     * Overriding the Id property from within ExpenseModel.Id in 
     * order to add [PrimaryKey] & [AutoIncrement]
     */

    [JsonIgnore]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public sealed override int Id { get; set; }

    /* 
     * This is the weird crap I had to do to get collections working with the 
     * overriden DTOs instead of the ExpenseModel versions while still
     * while still appeasing SQLite.
     * 
     */

    #region Navigation Properties

    [JsonProperty("Expenses")]   //This will allow the app to serialize this model and map ExpenseModelDto.ExpenseDtos to ExpenseModel.Expenses when it gets deserialized on the server
    [Ignore]
    public List<ExpenseModelDto.ExpenseDto> ExpenseDtos {
        get; set;
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Ignore]
    public override List<ExpenseModel.Expense> Expenses {
        get; set;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ExpenseModelDto() { }

    #endregion
}
```